# Using factory to create controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I was wondering whether I can use a factory to initialize a controller and then add it to a module. Code could look something like this, but this is not working:

```
const controllerFactory = {
  provide: DefinitionController,
  useFactory: async (service: DefinitionService) => {
    //initialization of controller
    return new DefinitionController();
  },
  inject: [DefinitionService],
};
@Module({
  controllers: [controllerFactory],
  providers: [DefinitionService],
})
export class DefinitionModule {}
```

It looks like using factories for controllers is not supported, but I am not sure. There is an example of [using factory for providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers), but I cannot find anything for controller in documentation or on google.

Comment: Why do you want to use a factory to define your controller? Is the service it uses dynamic or the controller initialization? It would help if you elaborated on your use case a little bit more. :-)

Comment: Or do you just want to initialize your controller (not dynamic)?

Comment: Well I am trying to add some new endpoints to controller based on some loaded data.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. See my edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to define your controller with an async factory comparable to custom providers. You cannot add dynamic endpoints/routes unless using the native express/fastify instance:

> At the moment there is no way to register a route dynamically except
>   by using the internal HTTP / Fastify / Express instance

There is an [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1438) where a dynamic routing module is discussed but this will probably not be part of nest very soon:

> At the moment both Kamil and I are really busy, so this issue may take
>   some time - except someone else takes on the task :)

---

But you can use the [OnModuleInit](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/lifecycle-events) lifecycle event to do static initialization:

```
@Injectable()
export class DefinitionController implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log(`Initialization...`);
  }
```

It will be called once when your app starts and has access to the injected providers in your controller, e.g. your `DefinitionService`.